# SSIS package with custom PipelineComponent upgrade from SQL 2008R2 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have upgraded my custom PipelineComponent from .net 3.5 to 4.0 and updated references from ...Server\100\SDK... to ...Server\110\SDK...
The release dll has been copied to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents\ as well as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents\ and install in GAC C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL.

I have install full SQL server 2012 and Visual Studio Data Tools for SQL2012.

Package is visible in SSIS Toolbox on Data Flow tab during edit SSIS package in Visual Studio.

During update process in Visual Studio 2010/2012 of package created in Visual Studio 2008 targeting SQL2008R2 the following error appear:

- Upgrading package PackageName.dtsx (Error)
  Messages
  Error 0xc0047062: DataFlowTaskName: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentUpgradeFailedException: The PC FxRate Lookup could not upgrade itself.[[The PerformUpgrade method failed.]]
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.PerformUpgrade(Int32 pipelineVersion)
  at MyCompanyName.Services.Infrastructure.DataFlow.PCDictionaryLookup`2.PerformUpgrade(Int32 pipelineVersion)
  at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 lPipelineVersion)

Error 0xc004801f: DataFlowTaskName: The component metadata for "PC FxRate Lookup" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

Error 0xc001f429: Package Upgrade: The loading of the package PackageName.dtsx has failed.

```
 [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1405:ComVisibleTypeBaseTypesShouldBeComVisible"), ComVisible(true)]
[
DtsPipelineComponent(
    CurrentVersion = 6,
    DisplayName = "PC FxRate Lookup",
    Description = "send to Output the corresponding value in a map via key from input for a given ScenarioId or a default value")

]
public class PCFxRateLookup : PCDictionaryLookup<string, double?>



[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1405:ComVisibleTypeBaseTypesShouldBeComVisible"), ComVisible(true)]
[
DtsPipelineComponent(
    ComponentType = ComponentType.Transform,
    DisplayName = "PC Dictionary Lookup",
    Description = "Output the corresponding value in a map via key from input for a given ScenarioId or a default value")
]
public abstract class PCDictionaryLookup<T1, T2> : PipelineComponent
{
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install it in the GAC using gacutil?

Comment: Yes, the one from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Answer (score 0):

The issue is was in custom SSIS PipelineComponent. Adding new component in SSIS data flow was without problems but upgrade - no.
I have to override PerformUpgrade method from PipelineComponent base class as below:

```
public override void PerformUpgrade(int pipelineVersion)
{
    DtsPipelineComponentAttribute attribute = (DtsPipelineComponentAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof(DtsPipelineComponentAttribute), false);
    int currentVersion = attribute.CurrentVersion;
    ComponentMetaData.Version = currentVersion;
}
```

After building project, placing dll in GAC and proper SQL folders I had to update the *.dtsx packages with Notepad.

1) Version=2.0.0.0 >> Version=4.0.0.0 (.net input parameters to custom SSIS packages).

2) Version=3.0.0.0 >> Version=4.0.0.0 (new version of custom SSIS packages).

After that, just use wizard to update SSIS solution.

That's it.